# How convert a string to binary in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Original byte value in `base16` *BINARY* format -

`7e-c2-8c-c2-8a-c7-61-60-34-b7-0e-de-c2-28-9e-b3-08-a6-c3-93-74-99-34-09-48-0c-60-e3-96-47-04-e3`

After converting it to *VARCHAR* - `7EC28CC28AC7616034B70EDEC2289EB308A6C39374993409480C60E3964704E3`

I need to convert it back to *BINARY* and for this I used the `TO_BINARY('7EC28CC28AC7616034B70EDEC2289EB308A6C39374993409480C60E3964704E3')` function,

but it returns `7EC28CC28AC7616034B70EDEC2289EB308A6C39374993409480C60E3964704E3`

instead of the desired `7e-c2-8c-c2-8a-c7-61-60-34-b7-0e-de-c2-28-9e-b3-08-a6-c3-93-74-99-34-09-48-0c-60-e3-96-47-04-e3`.

**Note** - `TO_BINARY(string,'base16')` doesn't work

Comment: How did you to convert to varchar and it appears both base 16 and varchar are same values expect hyphens are removed and capitalized?

Comment: I had converted it into varchar in Teradata using `from_bytes` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to strip the hyphens, and use [TO_BINARY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/to_binary.html) on ['HEX'](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/binary-input-output.html#hexadecimal-hex-format-example) input type

```
SELECT 
    '7e-c2-8c-c2-8a-c7-61-60-34-b7-0e-de-c2-28-9e-b3-08-a6-c3-93-74-99-34-09-48-0c-60-e3-96-47-04-e3' as tb_b16_str
    ,replace(tb_b16_str, '-') as no_hyphen
    ,to_binary(no_hyphen, 'HEX') as now_as_bin
    ,base64_encode(now_as_bin) as now_as_base64
;
```

| TB_B16_STR | NO_HYPHEN | NOW_AS_BIN | NOW_AS_BASE64 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7e-c2-8c-c2-8a-c7-61-60-34-b7-0e-de-c2-28-9e-b3-08-a6-c3-93-74-99-34-09-48-0c-60-e3-96-47-04-e3 | 7ec28cc28ac7616034b70edec2289eb308a6c39374993409480c60e3964704e3 | 7ec28cc28ac7616034b70edec2289eb308a6c39374993409480c60e3964704e3 | fsKMworHYWA0tw7ewiieswimw5N0mTQJSAxg45ZHBOM= |

if we take the BASE64, and paste that into notepad++ and BASE64 decode that, and save that as a bin file and open in a hex editor, we can see sure enough `now_as_bin` is correct decoded as expected..

[image: BASE64 to Binary and externally inspected to show it all worked]

### You already have a binary:

So thinking about this more, you are already successfully coverting the data to a Snowflake binary:

```
SELECT '7EC28CC28AC7616034B70EDEC2289EB308A6C39374993409480C60E3964704E3' as hex_str
    ,system$typeof(hex_str)
    ,TO_BINARY(hex_str) as now_as_binary
    ,system$typeof(now_as_binary);
```

The result you don't like the look of, it's a Snowflake binary.

| HEX_STR | SYSTEM$TYPEOF(HEX_STR) | NOW_AS_BINARY | SYSTEM$TYPEOF(NOW_AS_BINARY) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7EC28CC28AC7616034B70EDEC2289EB308A6C39374993409480C60E3964704E3 | VARCHAR(64)[LOB] | 7ec28cc28ac7616034b70edec2289eb308a6c39374993409480c60e3964704e3 | BINARY(8388608)[LOB] |

### How to export back to teradata:

Or you are really looking for "how to convert a binary to Teradata formatting string for exporting from Snowflake to Teradata"

So the step broken down:

```
SELECT 
    '7EC28CC28AC7' as hex_str
    ,TO_BINARY(hex_str) as now_as_binary
    ,hex_encode(now_as_binary) as back_to_hex
    ,REGEXP_REPLACE(back_to_hex, '(..)','\\1-') as made_chunky
    ,RTRIM(made_chunky, '-') as wanted
    ;
```

gives:

| HEX_STR | NOW_AS_BINARY | BACK_TO_HEX | MADE_CHUNKY | WANTED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7EC28CC28AC7 | 7ec28cc28ac7 | 7EC28CC28AC7 | 7E-C2-8C-C2-8A-C7- | 7E-C2-8C-C2-8A-C7 |

and that can be mashed together like:

```
SELECT 
    TO_BINARY('7EC28CC28AC7') as now_as_binary
    ,RTRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(hex_encode(now_as_binary), '(..)','\\1-'), '-') as made_chunky
    ;
```

| NOW_AS_BINARY | MADE_CHUNKY |
| --- | --- |
| 7ec28cc28ac7 | 7E-C2-8C-C2-8A-C7 |

Comment: Thanks! Very well explained